# Vuejs 2 Form Saves Twice

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm trying to save data with VueJS to a Go backend API.
When I click `submit`, the data is saved twice. I've tried to prevent this but something is missing.
I've tested the endpoint with Postman and it's saving normally.

Here is the component:

```html
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <form @submit.prevent="PostDominio">
      <hr />
      <label id="lbldom">Dominio </label>
      <input v-model="form.Titulo" type="text" />
      <button
        id="sendom"
        class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm shadow-sm p-1 mb-1"
        @click="PostDominio"
      >
        Gravar
      </button>
      <hr />
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        Titulo: '',
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    PostDominio() {
      axios
        .post('http://localhost:3000/dominios', this.form)
        .bind(this)
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `e.preventDefault` to the `PostDominio(e)` function and it solved my issue!

Comment: Yeah, à form will have a default behavior in HTML. So either prevent default it or use a button.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community I guess that it doesn't matter a lot here since OP is answering his own question.